# Converting hex digits to decimal for comparison (C)

Tags: c, string, numbers, hex, decimal

I'm trying to make a program that determines if an intel hex file is created correctly, and one program I'm using to generate them did not generate one correctly so I'm gonna make one.

So far, I can read a line from the target file, but I'm having a problem converting a hexadecimal number from a string to a number to compare. Here is my troubling snippet:

```
//hx=opened file handle
unsigned char hexv,hexsz,hexcs;
while ((line=getline(&hexstring,&buffer,hx))> -1){
      //Trying to convert hexadecimal character in byte 7 and 8 of string to number
      //Hexsz must contain actual number representing number of hex digits to process
      sprintf(hexsz,"%02x",hexstring[7]);
      //Checksum = 0
      hexcs=0;
      for (hexc=0;hexc<(hexsz*2);hexc+=2){
        //Add next hexadecimal number to checksum
        sprintf(hexv,"%02x",hexstring[9+hexc]);
        hexcs+=hexv;
      }
      //Check checksum with stored checksum
      sprintf(hexv,"%02x",hexstring[9+hexc]);
      if (hexcs != hexv){
        printf("HEX checksum error!\n");
      }
}
```

Something is wrong with these sprintf's and I can't figure it out.

The only thing I know of is to do the following:

1. Allocate a temporary char*
2. string copy the hex value to that char*
3. use strtol on that char

But isn't there a simpler way to go about it?

I tried strtol(startaddress,endaddress,16) to convert, and the program wouldn't recognize that. It expects endaddress to be NULL.

So what's the more simple way to convert a two-byte string in a large string to a hexadecimal?

For example, If my string is

```
:10007B00AB83AD8290015C938D828B83F531EF85E1
```

and I wanted to convert the value 7B from it, what's the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Why can't you use `strtol` on the whole hex string, or extract a digit pair to a temporary string and use `strtol` on that? You haven't clearly shown your use of `strtol`.

Answer (score 2):

> simple way to convert a two-byte string in a large string to a hexadecimal?

Isolate two characters and convert.

```
//               012345678 
const char *s = ":10007B00AB83AD8290015C938D828B83F531EF85E1";
int n = 5;

unsigned value;
if (sscanf(s + n, "%2x", &value) == 1) {
  printf("Value at %.2s: %02X\n", s+n, value);
} else {
  puts("Fail");
}
```

or

```
// Form a 3-char string such as '7', 'B', '\0'
const char substring[3] = { s[n], s[n+1] };
char *endptr;
long value = strtol(substring, &endptr, 16);
if (endptr > substring) {
  printf("Value at %s: %02X\n", substring, value);
} else {
  puts("Fail");
}
```

---

`strtol(startaddress,endaddress,16)` is the wrong use of `strtol()`.  `endptr` is the *address* of a pointer, not simply the end address.

```
long int strtol(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base);
```

"It expects endaddress to be NULL." --> Passing `NULL` here is OK, but then code lacks information to decide it conversion succeeded.  Instead, pass the address of a `char *`, as above.  Then test to see if a conversion happened.

---

Pedantic code would not use `s[n+1]` in `{ s[n], s[n+1] };` with out knowing `s[n]` is not a *null character*.  Yet I would expect a loop to have checked that already.

```
const char *s = ":10007B00AB83AD8290015C938D828B83F531EF85E1";

if (s[0] == ':') {
  unsigned n = 1;
  while (s[n] && s[n+1]) {
    const char substring[3] = { s[n], s[n+1] };
    ... 
    n += 2;
  }
  ...
```

`